# Custom error showing in MVC5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am making a MVC5 application, using EF6.5 and MSSQL. In a specific view i want to save a page with employee info, which i already can do succesfully. But there is an UNIQUE constraint on the username of the employee (obviously).

In my current situation, if the user tries to change their username to a username that already exists the application just throws an exception with information that the inputs violates the constraint in the database.

As i am not very fluent with all these webdevelopment languages i'd like to ask if there is an easy way to check if the username already exists upon submitting the view, and most important, show the employee an error saying he must choose an different username, preferrably without posting back to the controller, but if that has to happen, so be it.

Thanks in advance and i'd like to see your opinions and/or solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't normally allow users to change their usernames, partly for this reason.  If it's going to be possible, it should be an administrative task.  If you're talking about a display name (or a given name, a "real life" name), then that should be changeable but probably not have a `UNIQUE` constraint on it.  There's nothing stopping your company from hiring two people with the same name.

That said, if you want to allow someone to change a field that has a unique constraint on it, you should provide some kind of interface to check if the desired name is available.  This could be a custom SQL procedure that EF uses, such as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_CheckEmployeeName
(
    @empName VARCHAR(100) -- match this to the data type of the column
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM EmployeeTable WHERE UserName = @empName)
        RETURN 1;
    RETURN 0;
END
```

This is good if you have many clients (not necessarily using entity framework), and EF should be able to hook up to this function.  It should also be safer than checking the internal collection in EF, which might not be in sync at a given moment.  This function could also be used for other account creation purposes.

Your interface should have some wiring to call this function before actually trying to update the DB - maybe a button, maybe when the field loses focus, somethign like that.